# Unable to setup tor on arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, tor

I tried to install tor-browser-en package on arch linux using the yaourt by typing the command
`yaourt tor-browser-en`
. But while installing I get the error as

```
=> Validating source files with md5sums...
    cower-12.tar.gz ... Passed
    cower-12.tar.gz.sig ... Skipped
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    cower-12.tar.gz ... FAILED (unknown public key 1EB2638FF56C0C53)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
```

I cannot install it, help!a

Comment: Read the comments here: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tor-browser-en/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had visited the arch linux user repository page for tor-browser-en [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/tor-browser-en/?comments=all) and read the comment section. You would have seen that you should manually add the public key by typing in

```
gpg --keyserver pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys D1483FA6C3C07136
```

Do this and it should work fine.

Comment: I don't know how I missed it. Thank you anyways.